# Deploying to dokku (repo does not exist)

Tags: github, ssh, dokku

Hi I've been having trouble with dokku and basically it boils down to this:

```
git remote add dokku jasonh@app.com:ruby-getting-started
```

and then I get:

```
git push dokku master
jasonh@app.app.com's password:
fatal: 'ruby-getting-started' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

`dokku ssh-keys:list` - had my SSH key included. (created in Dokku and added to github)

```
dokku apps:create appname
```

seemed to create the app

```
    git remote -v returns dokku jasonh@app.app.com:ruby-getting-started (fetch)
dokku   jasonh@app.app.com:ruby-getting-started (push)
origin  git@github.com:myuser/ruby-getting-started.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:myuser/ruby-getting-started.git (push)
```

Seemed to create the app since its in the list. so what am i missing?

update ssh'd into my instance and added this

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub| sudo sshcommand acl-add dokku Jason_Laptop
[sudo] password for jasonh:
SHA256:*******************
```

update

cat ~/.ssh/public_dokku.pub - then copied the contents to my dokku RSA file.

output of the command is the same cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (cept i named my file dokku rsa or something)

Here is my git remote -v

```
dokku   jasonh@app.app.com:sameappnameaswhatIcreated
```

Listing SSH brings this key (and others) which i can verify as the name i picked.

```
SHA256:*********** NAME="Jason_Harder" SSHCOMMAND_ALLOWED_KEYS="no-agent-forwarding,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding,no-port-forwarding"
```

My config file in ~./ssh since my main ssh is for github.
    Host *
     AddKeysToAgent yes
     UseKeychain yes
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/public_dokku

Update:

My remote was improperly added originally as git add remote jason@app.com or w.e when it should have been dokku@app.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [dokku deployment guide](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment/), check first your ssh connection.

The fact you see `jasonh@app.app.com's password:` means SSH does not find your public key in dokku remote server, and falls back to the account password.
Add it, as [explained here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29533043-new-app-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository).

That is:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P "" -f dokku

# copy dokku.pub to jasonh@app.app.com:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
# make sure it is copied as one line.

# edit your local ~/.ssh/config file
# add to it:

Host dokku
  Hostname app.app.com
  User jasonh
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dokku
```

Check this is working with `ssh -v dokku`

You can then change your remote URL to:

```
git remote set-url dokku dokku:sameappnameaswhatIcreated
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204759/discussion-on-answer-by-vonc-deploying-to-dokku-repo-does-not-exist).