# added wrong ssh key in local machine for github how to correct on localmachine

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I am trying to setup my github account. I followed this tutorial https://linuxtechlab.com/how-to-install-github-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/
I have generated github account keys in a folder called `/home/debian/git_keys`
the keys are following `kiotie32_rsa  kiotie32_rsa.pub`
now while doing ssh-add I did a mistake I did

```
debian@osboxes:~/git_keys$ ssh-add 
Identity added: /home/debian/.ssh/id_rsa (debian@osboxes)
```

it added id_rsa on my local machine. That is my understanding. Which is not correct .
What should I do in this situation to add the keys I generated in `/home/debian/git_keys`
and remove the key which was previously added.

Comment: Just run `ssh-add /home/debian/git_keys/kiotie32_rsa`. You'll now have two keys listed (`ssh-add -l`).

Answer (score 0):

In addition [of `ssh-add`](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) (if you have protected your jey with a passphrase), you will need a `/home/debian/.ssh/config` file in order to reference that ssh key (which has a non-standard name)

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59453568/6309), that will change your SSH URL.